# Deriving de Morgan's law for set from basic laws of set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am sure that this is achievable (this is a question is asked by my tutor), the usual proving of de Morgan's law is to assume an element $x$ belongs to $(A \cup B)^{c} \implies x$ does not belong to $(A \cup B) \implies \cdots \implies x$ belongs to $A^{c} \cap B^{c}$

But I can only derive it from following laws

Communication：$A \cup B = B \cup A$; $A \cap B = B \cap A$;

Associativity: $(A\cap B)\cap C = A\cap(B\cap C)$; $(A\cup B)\cup C = A\cup(B\cup C)$;

Distribution: $(A\cap B)\cup C = (A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$; $(A\cup B)\cap C = (A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)$;

Identity: $A\cup\varnothing = A$; $A\cap U = A$;

Complement: $A\cup A^{c} = U; A\cap A^{c} = \varnothing$;

Definition of  $\setminus$: $A\setminus B = A\cap B^{c}$;

Definition of $\oplus$: $A\oplus B = (A∩B^{c})∪(A^{c}∩B)$

Idempotance: $A\cup A = A; A\cap A = A$;

Double complement: $(A^{c})^{c} = A$;

$A ⊕ U = A^{c}$

$(A \setminus C) \cup (B \setminus C) = (A \cup B) \setminus C$

I tried several ways, but it all come back to the origin, I got a hint that this is related to the definition of set difference (not sure about that), can anyone help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove De Morgan's Law: $(A \cap B)^c=A^c\cup B^c$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2814102/prove-de-morgans-law-a-cap-bc-ac-cup-bc)

Comment: If $x$ does not belong to $A\cup B$, then $x$ does not  belong to $A$, *and* $x$ does not belong to $B$. Therefore, ,,,

Comment: … Therefore, $x\in A^c$ and $x\in B^c$. //  You really went off the deep end citing all those identities in search of one that might help. It’s not that complicated, just reason about it. // The term is “Commutativity”.